# How to make a Blazor webserver app listen to a POST requests in an endpoint?

Tags: blazor-server-side

Coming from NodeJS, a simple example to listen to a POST request on an endpoint would be

```
var express = require("express");
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.post("/myendpoint", function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body);
});
app.listen(8080);
```

I'm trying to do the same in a Blazor server app. I created a class that is as it appears below

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/myendpoints")]
    public class MyEndpointController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void MyEndpoint(string inputJSON)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(inputJSON);
        }
    }
}
```

When I do a POST request to `https://localhost:5001/api/myendpoints/MyEndpoint` with the following JSON in the body

```
{
    "postcontent": "Lorem ipsum..."
}
```

I get `400 Bad Request. The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax. This response means that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.`

How would one make the app listen to the end point? Is the class `MyEndpointController` supposed to be passed somewhere on `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. First a model has to be created that matches the structure of the incoming JSON. The input will be automatically deserialized into that object.

For this example

```
// MyModel.cs
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string postcontent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then the Controller

```
// MyEndpointController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using MyApp.Models;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace MyApp.Controllers

{
    [ApiController]
    public class MyEndpointController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/MyEndpoint")]
        public void MyEndpoint(MyModel input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyModel>(input));
        }
    }
}
```

The received data on the method is deserialized into `MyModel`. To print it to the console, the object is serialized with `JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyModel>(input)`.

Finally, on `Startup.cs` in the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` method, `endpoints.MapControllers();` is supposed to be called when setting the endpoints

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Making a POST request with a consumer then has the server respond to the POST request and print the content on the server side. For example

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:5001/api/MyEndpoint' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"postcontent": "Lorem ipsum..."}'
```